# Django redirect to url in other app with kwargs

Tags: django

I'm trying to just log a user in by going to a `login-redirect` page, which then redirects to the users profile page. I understand that this is not the first time this question has been asked, but I've tried all the other answers and I have no idea why this isn't working for me.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name="login"),
    url(r'^login/redirect/$', account_redirect, name="account-redirect"),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': 'home'}, name="logout"),
    url(r'^stores/', include('stores.urls', namespace='store_app'))
]
```

**views.py**

```
def account_redirect(request):
    # tried both to see if it would help...
    # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('store_app:account-landing', kwargs= {"pk":request.user.pk,"name":request.user.vendor.name}))
    return redirect('store_app:account-landing', pk=request.user.pk, name=slugify(request.user.vendor.name))
```

**stores/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^account/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<name>\w+)/$', AccountLanding.as_view(), name="account-landing" ),
]
```

Based on serveral other answers to related questions, this should work fine, but it doesn't. After I login and get to `login/redirect/` I get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'account-landing' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 1, 'name': u'Fake Company'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'stores/account/(?P<pk>\\d+)/(?P<name>\\w+)/$']
```

I don't understand, it's trying the right pattern and has the right arguments? So why does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slugify` has a tendency to turn spaces into hyphens so chances are you need to include that into your url

```
^account/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<name>[\w-]+)/$
```

Note: This would only be the issue if 'Fake Company' is example data or the error you're showing is what appeared from when you were using the commented out line

The reason slugify does this is because url's can't contain spaces and instead they are turned into `%20`'s, which look ugly.

Comment: Works great now, don't know why I didn't think of that. And yes, the line I used was actually not commented out. Thanks!

Comment: @thefoxrocks - no worries, enjoy!